# Hello, I wanted to implement different css fonts in Windows and Mac for same page in web application. Can anyone provide me how can we achieve this

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webkit

My requirement is to apply font based on Operating system

For windows: "Segoe UI"
For Mac: "SF Pro"

I have tried using below code, but is loading before the DOM loads and not persistent

```
      if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
            {
                document.body.style.background = "green"; 
            }
```

Comment: And what do you want to do if the user is using Linux, Android, iOS?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value `navigator.userAgent` in the `data-` attribute of `html` tag via JavaScript and set the desired font in desired OS from `CSS` using attribute selector as follows:

```js
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

```css
html[data-useragent*='Mac OS X'] {
  font-family: 'SF Pro', sans-serif;
}

html[data-useragent*='Win'] {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800; 
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, corrupti! Dolore, repellat quo modi minus, aliquid mollitia amet suscipit ipsam quisquam esse, inventore quod tempore consequatur sint! Sapiente saepe quidem omnis, voluptatibus, cumque impedit maiores iste culpa asperiores accusamus assumenda temporibus minus adipisci porro odit ut reiciendis quia incidunt dolores!</p>
```

[OS Specific Font - CSS Trics](https://css-tricks.com/os-specific-fonts-css/)

Answer (score 0):

put in in a [useEffect with empty dependency list](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects)

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ... your code here
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
            {
                document.body.style.background = "green"; 
            }
}, [])
```